# OpenLayers label without using StyleMap

Tags: openlayers-2, style

I need to show label of each feature based on attribute field value. I know that I can use ${attribute} notation for this purpose. But this approach works only if I make StyleMap and pass it to vector layer constructor. But in this case I can not modify style of each features separately. How I can make layer with labels and with not null value of style property of each feature?

My current config:

```js
var custom_style = {
    fill: true,
    fillColor: "#feb24c",
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeColor: '#3182bd',
    strokeWidth: 1
};

var l = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Coverage", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "http://***:8088/collect",
        format: new ol.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: custom_style
});
```

If I add `label: ${attribute}` to custom_style object, then text `${attribute}` will be shown on map, not value of attribute.

Comment: are you having problems because some features have null value?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process each feature and display something different depending on the value of a feature attribute, you can supply a function via the style context that returns different values. [Here's an example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93562/get-and-change-style-property-openlayers/93691#93691). However, this approach does use a style map - I'm not sure if you want to avoid using one for some reason.

The value of the label is generated by the assigned function.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. Variables are only evaluated in `StyleMap` objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the label, probably this may work:

```
label: '${attribute}'
```

Here I modified your code with it:

```
var custom_style = {
    fill: true,
    fillColor: "#feb24c",
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeColor: '#3182bd',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    label: '${attribute}'
};

var l = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Coverage", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "http://***:8088/collect",
        format: new ol.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: custom_style
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work as I mentioned above.

Comment: could you post some images showing what you have and what you expect?